# Is there a way to install Apache Bench (ab) without installing apache

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, yum, ab

Can you provide instuctions on how to install ab on a fedora distro with or without installing the apache web server? With yum or compiling from source.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Install apr-util(need to run ab):

```
yum install apr-util
```

Install yum-utils:

```
yum install yum-utils
```

Download httpd an extract ab:

```
mkdir ~/httpd
cd ~/httpd
yumdownloader httpd
rpm2cpio httpd-2.2.3-43.el5.centos.3.i386.rpm | cpio -idmv
mv usr/bin/ab /usr/bin/ab
cd ~
rm -rf ~/httpd
```

Run ab:

```
ab http://google.ru/
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.0.40-dev <$Revision: 1.146 $> apache-2.0
```

Comment: On ubuntu you could do sudo apt-get install apache2-utils

Comment: On Arch -- `pacman -S apr-util`

Answer (score 70):

On my CentOS 6.2, this worked:

```
sudo yum install httpd-tools
```

Comment: Worked on my Fedora 17 as well! Thanks!  :-)

Comment: Works on CentOS 6

Comment: Works on RHEL 6.6

Comment: Centos 7 working like charm

Answer (score 1):

This should help you. It depends upon on Apache Portable Runtime library and APR-util library

http://code.google.com/p/apachebench-standalone/wiki/HowToBuild

Comment: I actually tried that before I posted the answer, but hasn't been updated and it's not compatible with late versions of APR - No matter what, I couldn't get it to compile.

Answer (score 1):

For those who came here looking for Apache Benchmark (*ab*) binary, you should know that *ab* can be slow sometimes (testing nginx for example). 
Also, it requires *apr-util* to be installed (with sudo), and there is no standalone binary to download.

Instead, I'd recommend an alternative - ***wrk*** - it is faster and requires no dependencies:

https://github.com/wg/wrk

(Or the GO variant: https://github.com/tsliwowicz/go-wrk )