# How to install Apache Benchmark on CentOS?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, yum, ab

I try to install Apache Benchmark using [Is there a way to install Apache Bench (ab) without installing apache](https://serverfault.com/questions/240496/is-there-a-way-to-install-apache-bench-ab-without-installing-apache) solutions on my centos but when i run `yumdownloader httpd`, i get error:

```
root@local [~/httpd]# yumdownloader httpd
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: yum.phx.singlehop.com
 * elrepo: repos.lax-noc.com
 * extras: centos.tcpdiag.net
 * updates: mirror.stanford.edu
No Match for argument httpd
Nothing to download
```

What is it? and how can i fixed it?

Edit 1:
i try to use Michael Hampton way but i get this errors:

```
root@local [~]# yum provides /usr/bin/ab
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: yum.phx.singlehop.com
 * elrepo: repos.lax-noc.com
 * extras: centos.tcpdiag.net
 * updates: mirror.stanford.edu
No Matches found

root@local [~]# yum install httpd-tools
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: yum.phx.singlehop.com
 * elrepo: repos.lax-noc.com
 * extras: centos.tcpdiag.net
 * updates: mirror.stanford.edu
Setting up Install Process
No package httpd-tools available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You can discover which package contains the program you want using `yum provides`:

```
yum provides /usr/bin/ab
```

Then you will see that `ab` is in the `httpd-tools` package.

And now you can install it:

```
yum install httpd-tools
```

---

Beginning with RHEL/CentOS 7, you can also supply a filename contained within a package, and `yum` will automatically locate and install the corresponding package.

```
yum install /usr/bin/ab   # RHEL 7
dnf install /usr/bin/ab   # RHEL 8
```

Comment: tanx a lot for answer but i get error again .. please check Edit 1

Comment: You excluded some packages, or otherwise trashed your yum configuration. Check the `/etc/yum.conf` and files in the `/etc/yum.repos.d` directory for inappropriate exclusions.

Comment: tanx a lot, its for /etc/yum.conf , that excluded httpd :D

Comment: You can also just run `sudo yum install /usr/bin/ab`

Comment: @KingPong solution did the trick.